# jquery find function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, find

I have html with 2

```
<select> ... </select>
```

elements inside a span with class spanClass. Now i am trying to select those selects with jQuery with this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    spans = jQuery('.spanClass');
    spans.each(function() {

        var inputs = jQuery(this).find('select');
        console.log(inputs);// This is working
        inputs.each(function() {
            alert('test'); //This not
       });
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <select name="een">
            <option> test </option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>

        <select name="twee">
            <option> test </option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

However, this is not working, can anybody tell me why?

Comment: it looks fine - can you share the html sample

Comment: You are having incorrect DOM. you have not wrapped second select correctly in tr and td elements. also fiddle works fine for dom you have mentioned. http://jsfiddle.net/ca8st4oz/

Comment: I don't think spans (inline elements) are supposed to contain tables (block elements). Depending on doctype, the table may be built outside its would-be span container. The fact that someone has got this HTML working in a fiddle doesn't mean that it will work under all doctypes in all browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First>** Put Table inside Div instead of Span (it's the correct way to do this)

**Second>** Correct your table tags as the following image and codes (some of them are incorrect!)

**Now>** Use these codes

**HTML:**

```
<div class="divClass">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="een">
                <option> test </option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="twee">
                <option> test </option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    spans = jQuery('.divClass');
    spans.each(function() {

        var inputs = jQuery(this).find('select');
        console.log(inputs);
        inputs.each(function() {
            console.log(jQuery(this).prop("name")); 
       });
    });
});
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
var inputs = jQuery(this).find('select');   // Isn't inputs empty jQueryObject? length 0?
```

if inputs is empty jQueryObject, the callback function passed by .each() is never called.